# word choice: enhance/increase standards

Tags: word-choice

I consulted the collocation dictionary and found the verbs "raise" and "improve" are commonly used with "standards." But **I'm wondering if I can use the words "enhancing" or "increasing" in the following passage.** Thanks for help.

As our survey shows, consumer power has great implications for companies, because it is changing the way people stop. Many firms already claim to be "customer-driven" or "customer-centered." Now their claims will be tested as never before. Taking advantage of shopper's ignorance will no longer be possible: people will know--and soon tell others, even those without the Internet--that prices in the next town are lower or that certain goods are inferior. **The Internet is working wonders in ________ standards.** Good and honest firms should benefit most.

Answer (score 1):

The word you are looking for is *improving*.

*Increase* means "to grow larger".  If you used to have four dollars and now you have five dollars, your savings has increased.  A "standard" does not have a size.

*Enhance* means improve by addition.  Having five dollars instead of four might enhance your buying power, but going to a cheaper store does not: your buying power is increased, but technically not enhanced.

It's a subtle distinction, and not one worth learning, since *enhance* has been destroyed as a meaningful word through overuse by bureaucrats and marketing types.  Just avoid it altogether and say "improve".

Answer (score 0):

I think your choice of words is somewhat limited by the use of "standards". That word has at least two relevant meanings:

(1) a set of rules to which organisations are *expected* to adhere,
(2) a level of service which organisations *actually* provide.

You are using the word "standards" in the second sense, but if you choose less idiomatic phrases could easily be interpreted in the first. For that reason, I'd stick with **raise standards**.

You could instead opt to use a different word/phrase instead of "standards". One natural alternative might be "the customer experience".